# One to many mapping in Zend Framwork 2 with doctrine 2

Tags: zend-framework, zfdoctrine

How to use sql joins in zend framwork 2 with Doctrine 2 ?

I want to join to column std_id in student table and user id in user table .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this in the Doctrine documentation:

[Doctrine2 : one-to-one unidirectional mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-unidirectional)

I assume in ZF2/Doctrine2 you will have to put "ORM\" before the Doctrine annotations:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Shipping")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="shipping_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
```

(edit: added zf2 variant of annotation)